# Finding the best gaussian fit to three slopes

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have a data set where using simulation, I get data in the form of $\partial F(p, in)/\partial p$. I get $\partial F/\partial p$ at three discrete instances of $p$ i.e., $p-\Delta p,~p,~ \&~p+\Delta p$.

I want to find the mean & variance of a Gaussian pdf that best fits the slope of the responses at these instances of $p$.
Since we want to fit slopes to the gaussian and not the actual values, I believe the equation for gaussian distribution needs to be differentiated and then used for a fit.

If $ g\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sigma.\sqrt{2.\pi}}e^\frac{-\left(x-\mu\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}$  is the equation for gaussian, differentiating $g(x)$, we will get
$g'\left(x\right)=\frac{-\left(x-\mu\right)}{\sigma^3.\sqrt{2.\pi}}e^\frac{-\left(x-\mu\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}$
I have written a function with example data in python for this problem.

```
####program starts here####
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

#### Data starts here ####
x = [9.8e-05, 0.0001, 0.00010200000000000001]
#### please note x = [p-dp, p, p+dp] ####
y = [-706.883051, -692.742301, -679.162872]
#### please note y = [dF/d(p-dp), dF/dp, dF/d(p+dp)] ####
#### Data ends here ####

def func(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return (-(x-x0)/(2*math.sqrt(math.pi)*sigma**3))*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))
# Executing curve_fit on input data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y) 
#popt returns the best fit values for parameters of the given model (func)
print (popt)
####program ends here######
```

the output that I am getting for popt and pcov are as follows:

```
popt = [ 1.0000000e+00 -1.2440869e+06  1.3967266e+02]
pcov = array([[inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf]])
```

I am stuck here because the data I get is not making sense. The input that I have provided is just one example. Also, I aunsure how to I use the output to get the mean & variance of the resultant Gaussian.